# Remove styled maps button from Styled Google map

Tags: google-maps

is there a way of removing the option of viewing the styled or normal map on google maps? When it is styled? And the other buttons like map and satellite?

like on this page:

http://demo.hongkiat.com/google-maps-styles/

Thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a View Source on that page, you can see how it works. It uses the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and in particular the [StyleMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StyledMapType)). Here's [a Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple) and [another example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-complex). And this [Style Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) is useful for trying out style options.

For the question of viewing either the styled or normal map, read through the Maps API docs for information on custom controls. You can add controls to the map that work like the standard ones, or you can have no controls on the map at all. It's completely up to you.

Now if your question is how to change [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/) itself, your options there are much more limited. You may find something useful in the [My Maps](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62843). If not, then you have to build your own map using the Maps API, where you can customize it in numerous ways.